# are Triangles Similar?

Tags: javascript, typescript, geometry

You have two triangles a1 b1 c1 and a2 b2 c3 on a plane. Your task is to determine whether they are, i.e. if their corresponding angles have the same measurements.

coordinates is an

array []

```
let coord = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3, -3, 0];
```

where a1 is (coord[0],coord[1]), b1 (coord[2],coord[3]) ...

```js
let s = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3, -3, 0]

function areTrianglesSimilar(c) {
    
    let result = null
    let line1 = (Math.abs(c[2]) - Math.abs(c[0])) + (Math.abs(c[3]) - Math.abs(c[1]))
    let line2 = (Math.abs(c[4]) - Math.abs(c[0])) + (Math.abs(c[5]) - Math.abs(c[1]))
    let line3 = Math.abs(Math.sqrt( Math.pow(line1, 2)+ Math.pow(line2, 2)))
    console.log(line1, line2, line3)
    
    let angle1 = Math.atan2(line1, line2) * 180 / Math.PI
    let angle2 = Math.atan2(line1, line3) * 180 / Math.PI
    let angle3 = 180 - (angle1 + angle2)
    console.log(angle1, angle2, angle3)
    let arr1 = []
    
    arr1.push(angle1, angle2, angle3)
    
    
    let line4 = (Math.abs(c[8]) - Math.abs(c[6])) + (Math.abs(c[9]) - Math.abs(c[7]))
    let line5 = (Math.abs(c[10]) - Math.abs(c[0])) + (Math.abs(c[11]) - Math.abs(c[1]))
    let line6 = Math.abs(Math.sqrt( Math.pow(line4, 2)+ Math.pow(line5, 2)))
    console.log(line4, line5, line6)
    
    let angle4 = Math.atan2(line4, line5) * 180 / Math.PI
    let angle5 = Math.atan2(line4, line6) * 180 / Math.PI
    let angle6 = 180 - (angle4 + angle5)
    console.log(angle6, angle5, angle4)
    
    if (arr1.includes(angle4) && arr1.includes(angle5) && arr1.includes(angle6)){
        return result = true
    } else return result = false
    

}

console.log(areTrianglesSimilar(s))
```

this was my try but did not pass all tests, any better idea?

Thanks to Mbo

```js
function areTrianglesSimilar(c) {
  let dx1 = c[2] - c[0];
  let dy1 = c[3] - c[1];
  let dx2 = c[4] - c[0];
  let dy2 = c[5] - c[1];
  let dx3 = c[4] - c[2];
  let dy3 = c[5] - c[3];

  let l1 = Math.sqrt(dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1);
  let l2 = Math.sqrt(dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2);
  let l3 = Math.sqrt(dx3 * dx3 + dy3 * dy3);
    console.log(l1,l2,l3);
  let angle12 = Math.acos((dx1 * dx2 + dy1 * dy2) / (l1 * l2));
  let angle13 = Math.acos((dx1 * dx3 + dy1 * dy3) / (l1 * l3));
  let angle23 = Math.acos((dx3 * dx2 + dy3 * dy2) / (l3 * l2));
  console.log(angle12, angle13, angle23);

  let dx4 = c[8] - c[6];
  let dy4 = c[9] - c[7];
  let dx5 = c[10] - c[6];
  let dy5 = c[11] - c[7];
  let dx6 = c[10] - c[8];
  let dy6 = c[11] - c[9];
  let l4 = Math.sqrt(dx4 * dx4 + dy4 * dy4);
  let l5 = Math.sqrt(dx5 * dx5 + dy5 * dy5);
  let l6 = Math.sqrt(dx6 * dx6 + dy6 * dy6);
    console.log(l4,l5,l6);
  let angle45 = Math.acos((dx4 * dx5 + dy4 * dy5) / (l4 * l5));
  let angle46 = Math.acos((dx4 * dx6 + dy4 * dy6) / (l4 * l6));
  let angle56 = Math.acos((dx6 * dx5 + dy6 * dy5) / (l6 * l5));
    console.log(angle45, angle46, angle56);

    if (angle12 == angle45 && angle13 == angle46){
        console.log('result'+':'+ true);
    } else console.log("result" + ":" + false);

}

let coordinates = [3, 4, 4, 7, 6, 1, -2, -1, 0, 5, 4, -7];

console.log(areTrianglesSimilar(coordinates))
```

Comment: this let coordinates = [3, 4, 4, 7, 6, 1, -2, -1, 0, 5, 4, -7] was one did not pass my function.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a number of errors here.  Aside from these, you should probably consider refactoring the code into separate functions which encapsulate commonly performed calculations.  This will cut down on needless repetition and make copy-paste typos less possible.  It will also make the code a little more self-documenting, which allows human beings to understand what you're doing better.

Assuming you want to determine the angles of the triangles and compare them (but you could also use side length ratios as @MBo pointed out), the general approach I would follow is this:

- Write a function to convert the coordinates array into a pair of `Triangle` objects, where a `Triangle` is a three-[tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of `Point` objects, defined like this:

  ```
  type Triangle = [Point, Point, Point];
  interface Point { x: number, y: number };

  function toTrianges(coords: number[]): [Triangle, Triangle] {
    // implement this
  }
  ```
- Write a function that takes three `Point`s, A, B, and C, and returns the (absolute value of the) measure of angle ∡ABC (with B as the vertex) in, say, degrees:

  ```
  function measureAngleABC(a: Point, b: Point, c: Point): number {
      // implement this
  }
  ```
- In order to do that, you might want to write functions that turn two `Point`s A and B and produces the `Vector` from A to B, and that manipulate vectors:

  ```
  type Vector = Point;
  function vector(a: Point, b: Point): Vector { /* impl */ }
  function vectorLength(v: Vector): number { /* impl */ }
  function dotProduct(v1: Vector, v2: Vector): number { /* impl */ }
  ```

  Note that the (unsigned) angle between two vectors can be determined by examining their lengths and their [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition).
- Once you have these, you should be able to turn a `Triangle` into a (sorted) triplet of its (unsigned) angles:

  ```
  type TriangleAngles = [number, number, number];
  function angles(triangle: Triangle): TriangleAngles { /* impl * }
  ```
- And finally, write a function that compares two `TriangleAngles` for *near*-equality.  Not *actual* equality using `===`, which is [fraught with troubles](https://dev.to/alldanielscott/how-to-compare-numbers-correctly-in-javascript-1l4i).  Since floating-point `number`s do not have infinite precision, two different calculations that should yield the same quantity might actually produce two different floating-point results.  The famous example is that `0.1 + 0.2 === 0.3` is `false`.  When you compare two `TriangleAngles`, you need to decide how close is "close enough" to call two triangles similar:

  ```
  function areNearlyEqual(ta1: TriangleAngles, ta2: TriangleAngles): boolean {
     // impl here
  }
  ```

I'm not going to write out how to implement these, since this looks like an exercise that benefits you most if you actually do it, not if someone does it for you.

---

In any case, here are the errors I see in your code:

- The line `(Math.abs(c[10]) - Math.abs(c[0])) + (Math.abs(c[11]) - Math.abs(c[1]))` looks like a typo with indices, as you are seemingly comparing a point from one triangle with a point on a different triangle.  This sort of typo would be much less likely if you refactor so as to move from an array of numbers to something like a pair of `Triangle`s.
- All code of the form `Math.abs(c[k])` for some index `k` is highly suspect. This treats `c[k] === 100` identically to `c[k] === -100`.  If you take a triangle and flip the sign of the x or y coordinate of one of its vertices, you are almost certainly going to change the shape of the triangle by reflecting that vertex across the x or y axis:

  [image: two dissimilar triangles]

  If your code can't tell the difference between those two triangles, it's not going to be able to accurately determine if two triangles are similar or not.
- The line `let line1 = (Math.abs(c[2]) - Math.abs(c[0])) + (Math.abs(c[3]) - Math.abs(c[1]))` and its brethren seem to looking at one of the sides of one of the triangles and *adding* the x component of its length to the y component of its length to get a single number. This doesn't represent much of anything that I can think of.  The *vector* of x-component-of-length and y-component-of-length are important, but when you just add the components together you are throwing away information you need.  You can verify this for yourself by coming up with a triangle where swapping `c[2]` and `c[3]` will change its shape, but the above code will not see a difference.
- The line `let line3 = Math.abs(Math.sqrt( Math.pow(line1, 2)+ Math.pow(line2, 2)))` seems to assume that `line1` and `line2` represent the lengths of two sides of a right triangle and `line3` is the length of the hypotenuse.  But unless your two sides are really perpendicular to each other, this will not be true.
- The line `let angle2 = Math.atan2(line1, line3) * 180 / Math.PI` is calculating an angle, but what angle? You can only use the arctangent to get an angle from the opposite and adjacent sides of a right triangle.  But there might be no right triangles here, and since `line3` was earlier assumed to be the hypotenuse of a right triangle where one of the sides was `line1`, there's no way `line3` is now one of the perpendicular legs.

Um, I think I have to stop here.  Suffice it to say that I would be very surprised if you could get this algorithm working by tweaking it.  I'd strongly recommend starting over with reusable functions that perform well-defined calculations.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is completely wrong. Dot product approach:

```
dx1 = c[2] - c[0]
dy1 = c[3] - c[1]
dx2 = c[4] - c[0]
dy2 = c[5] - c[1]
dx3 = c[4] - c[2]
dy3 = c[5] - c[3]
l1 = Math.sqrt(dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1)
l2 = Math.sqrt(dx2*dx2+dy2*dy2)
l3 = Math.sqrt(dx3*dx3+dy3*dy3)
angle12 = Math.acos((dx1*dx2+dy1*dy2)/(l1*l2)
```

and similar for angle13, and later you need to compare only two angles for equality

```
if angle12 == angle45 and angle13 == angle46 ...
```

or use some epsylon value to avoid floating calculation errors

```
if abs(angle12 -angle45) < 0.0000001 ...
```

Moreover, you can avoid angles and compare side length ratios

```
if l1/l4==l2/l5 and l1/l4==l3/l6...
```

Comment: You right in the calculation, and maybe for length ratios